# Example of using Excel built in function in Apache POI

Tags: excel, vba, apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Apache POI, I wonder if I want to use the builtin function from excel VBA, how can I do that?

For example:

In VBA, I can write something like:

```
Dim month as String
month = MonthName(  Month(  Sheets1.Range("C12")  )  )
```

How can I use that function in Apache POI(I do not wanna give that formula to a cell and evaluate it)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

POI does not provide a VBA engine, so you cannot execute VBA with POI.

But there's a way to implement equivalent code in Java and use it with POI. The link below gives an example of how to do that.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is so sad.

Answer (score 2):

`Apache poi` cannot interpret `VBA` but of course it has a formula evaluator. So of course you can evaluate `Excel` formulas directly in `apache poi` code.

But the `VBA` function `MonthName` is not implemented by default. So either you do getting the date from the cell, what is clearly possible using `apache poi`. And then, you get the month and the month name out of that date using `Java` code. This is called first approach in following example.

Or you are using a implemented `Excel` function. `TEXT` for example. This is called second approach in following example.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.*;

public class ExcelEvaluateMonthFunctions{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet2");

  java.util.Locale.setDefault(java.util.Locale.US);

  //first approach: 
  String monthname = null;
  java.util.Date date = sheet.getRow(11).getCell(2).getDateCellValue(); //Sheet2!C12 must contain a date

  java.time.LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
  monthname = localDate.getMonth().getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle.FULL, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
  System.out.println(monthname);

  //second approach:
  monthname = null;
  CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  XSSFFormulaEvaluator formulaevaluator = (XSSFFormulaEvaluator)helper.createFormulaEvaluator();
  WorkbookEvaluator workbookevaluator = formulaevaluator._getWorkbookEvaluator();

  ValueEval valueeval = null;
  valueeval = workbookevaluator.evaluate("TEXT(" + sheet.getSheetName() +"!C12, \"MMMM\")", null); //Sheet2!C12 must contain a date
  if (valueeval instanceof StringValueEval) {
   monthname = ((StringValueEval)valueeval).getStringValue();
  }
  System.out.println(monthname);

  workbook.close();
 }  
}
```